# SSRS : Change the colour of the text according to the result of the calculation

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to make a calculation that will take into account two data from two columns.

The columns are : *Average Export Quantity* (number) and *Export Delay* (number). The expression will be set on the Info column (number).

I would like my quantity info column to appear in red. The formatting would be as follows: If the average export quantity divided by 40x the average export time is less than the value in the quantity info column, put the text in red.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear, it sounds like you want to compare one expression to the results of another ? If so, set the background color property of the cell containing the quantity info to something like

```
IIF(
    Fields!AverageExportQuantity.Value / (40 * Fields!ExportDelay.Value) < [insert quantity info expression here],
    "Red",
    Nothing
   )
```

Swap you the field names I guess with your real ones - Note they are case sensitive.

Also, if you have an express in you r quantity info column alreay, that's what you'll need to use where I have stated `[insert quantity info expression here]` excluding the `=` sign.

If this does not help, show some sample data with actual field names form the dataset and any exist expression that are relevant.